# SQL statement to get the records with max(property) of a group

Tags: mysql, sql

Given following Table

```
select rv, mv, datetime, rawv from mytable where datetime > '2012-01-30';
+------+------+---------------------+------+
| rv   | mv   | datetime            | rawv |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
|    5 |   81 | 2012-01-31 07:00:00 |    1 |
|    5 |   81 | 2012-01-31 07:01:00 |    2 |
|    5 |   82 | 2012-01-31 07:00:00 |    3 |
|    5 |   82 | 2012-01-31 07:01:00 |    4 |
|    5 |   83 | 2012-01-31 08:00:00 |    5 |
|    5 |   83 | 2012-01-31 08:01:00 |    6 |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
```

I'm looking for a SQL-statement which provides the records with the maximal `datetime` value for each `rv`, `mv` group. The result should look like:

```
+------+------+---------------------+------+
| rv   | mv   | max(datetime)       | rawv |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
|    5 |   81 | 2012-01-31 07:01:00 |    2 |
|    5 |   82 | 2012-01-31 07:01:00 |    4 |
|    5 |   83 | 2012-01-31 08:01:00 |    6 |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
```

Do you know such a statement?

What I've tried so far is following, but as you can see I'm getting wrong results:

```
select rv, mv, max(datetime), rawv from mytable
where mv in (81,82,83)
group by rv, mv;
+------+------+---------------------+------+
| rv   | mv   | max(datetime)       | rawv |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
|    5 |   81 | 2012-01-31 07:01:00 |    0 |
|    5 |   82 | 2012-01-31 07:01:00 |    0 |
|    5 |   83 | 2012-01-31 08:01:00 |    5 |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.72 sec)
```

and

```
select rv, mv, datetime, rawv from mytable
where mp_nb in (81,82,83)
and datetime=(select max(datetime) from met_value);

+------+------+---------------------+------+
| rv   | mv   | datetime            | rawv |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
|    5 |   83 | 2012-01-31 08:01:00 |    6 |
+------+------+---------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.rv, t1.mv, t1.datetime, t1.rawv FROM mytable t1
  JOIN (SELECT rv, mv, MAX(datetime) datetime FROM mytable GROUP BY rv, mv) t2
    ON t1.rv = t2.rv AND t1.mv = t2.mv AND t1.datetime = t2.datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

This a pretty common question, and you'll find similar questions/answers under the "max-n-per-group" tag on Stack Overflow.

The usual way to do this is to join `mytable` to itself with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT a.rv, a.mv, a.datetime, a.rawv
FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b
 ON a.rv=b.rv AND a.mv=b.mv
 AND a.datetime < b.datetime
WHERE a.mv IN (81,82,83)
AND b.datetime IS NULL;
```

The general form of this query is:

```
SELECT a.[colnames I want]
FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b
 ON a.[colnames to GROUP BY] = b.[colnames to GROUP BY]
 AND a.[colname I want MAX of] < b.[colname I want MAX of]
WHERE b.[colname I want MAX of] IS NULL
[and any other where conditions]
```

It basically joins the table to itself on your mv and rv columns, and makes pairs of datetimes within each mv,rv group such that a's is less than b.

If there's a row in a such that there is no greater value in b (ie b.datetime IS NULL), then you have precisely the max for that group.

Comment: Hmm I've tried your statement but it doesn't complete (even after minutes). Anyway, +1 for the search hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix aggregate and non-aggregate columns like that.

From your dataset I noticed that `rawv` also increases with time. If that's true, you can also `MAX` it.

```
select rv, mv, max(datetime), max(rawv)
from mytable
where mv in (81,82,83)
group by rv, mv;
```

Comment: There's unfortunately no guarantee for the increasing

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: use other answers then, they are more correct :-)